# How to Monitor Oracle DB Active Sessions using Nagios

Tags: linux, oracle, nagios

How to Monitor Oracle DB,  Active Sessions using Nagios monitoring

Answer (score 0):

That depends on if you are using *core* or *XI*.
[Oracle Monitoring](https://www.nagios.com/solutions/oracle-monitoring/)
If you are using the open-source product, you will probably want to upload the relevant plugin to */usr/local/nagios/libexec*
[Nagios Exchange](https://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Databases/Oracle)